# How to get the progress of Promise.all and axios requests

Tags: axios, parallel-processing, progress-bar, es6-promise

I need to load 250 pictures from an API which I initially did with a for loop, but that took a very long time to finish.
On every finished request I incremented a counter to display a progress bar.

I rewrote the code to use `Promise.all` but struggle to display a proper progress bar:

```js
async load(warehouse) {
        
  await Promise.all(
    this.warehouse[warehouse].articles.map((article) =>
      axios
        .get(
          "https://my.api/articles/pictures/" +
            article.number
        )
        .then(this.warehouse[warehouse].progress++),
    ),
  ).then((responses) => {
    responses.map((img, index) => {
      this.warehouse[warehouse].articles[index].picture= img.data;
    });
  });

}
```

In the Firefox developer tools I see that the requests are done in parallel but they finish not all at the same time, so I have a few seconds until all are finished.
The progress is only updated after all requests are finished.

Is `Promise.all` the right approach for a scenario like this or is there a right/better way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

> Is `Promise.all` the right approach for a scenario like this

Yes.

> The progress is only updated after all requests are finished.

If you refer to the incrementing of `progress`, then these increments do not happen *after* all requests have finished, but at the time the requests are *initiated*.

The problem is with `.then(this.warehouse[warehouse].progress++)`

This will increase the `progress` property immediately, and pass the previous value of `progress` as argument to the `then` method (and as this is a number and not a callback function, it is ignored). The incrementing happens *synchronously*, irrespective of the state of the asynchronous request.

This incrementing should happen in a callback. At the same time that callback should echo again the response, so that the promise that is "mapped" to the `Promise.all` argument, resolves with the reponse from the request.

You'd also want to somehow *see* the progress, like with `console.log` or another visual clue:

```
.then((response) => {
      console.log(++this.warehouse[warehouse].progress);
      return response;
});
```